# TimeSeriesRescale seems to work oddly

Tags: date-and-time, time-series

I have been attempting to do some date computations with EventSeries, a convenient form for storing economic quantities (like expenses) over time. Following the documentation, I created an list of lists of the form `{n,$}` and then attempted to rescale using DatePlus and "Months". Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
initalD = {2020, 6, 1};
seqL = Thread[List[Range[5], ConstantArray[10, 5]]];
es = EventSeries[seqL];
rescaleES = 
 TimeSeriesRescale[
  es, {initalD, DatePlus[initalD, {5, "Months"}]}]
```

When I look at the rescaled, normalized EventSeries, it looks like this:

[image]

The first and last dates are correct, but the intermediate dates are not what I expected/wanted (the first of each month). When I look at the EventSeries, it has a Minimum Increment of 38 days, which seems quite random (I tried several different "Month" totals and they all produce minimum increments above what I would have expected.)

Here is what this looks like:

[image]

So I have two questions. First, does this seem like correct behavior and if so can you explain the rationale to me. Second, is there a way to set the Minimum Increment (can't find any reference to this in the docs) or other method to make the rescaled series start on the first of each month (short of creating my own rescaling function which would be fairly easy to do but..) TIA.